# Reading material for an analytical aspect of Kähler Geometry

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am currently reading the paper "Three-circle theorem and dimension estimate for holomorphic functions on Kähler manifolds" by Gang Liu and would like to see if anyone could recommend some books on the analytical aspect of Kähler geometry. More specifically, are there any books in analysis on Kähler geometry/ Kähler-Ricci flow that is written in a way like Peter Li's "Geometric Analysis" or Chow-Lu-Ni's "Hamilton's Ricci Flow"?

Your help is very much appreciated.

————-———————————

Edit: I found Well’s “Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds” to be quite similar to what I am looking for, but not very specifically treating the case of Kähler geometry.

Edit 2: I also found Ballmann's "Lectures on Kähler Manifolds" to be a good introduction to the subject of Kähler geometry with a little bit of geometric analysis on Kähler manifolds. But I would also like to see a more analysis-oriented book. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Gang Tian's book _Canonical Metrics in Kähler geometry_ is excellent. The lecture notes on the Kähler--Ricci flow by Jian Song and Ben Weinkove and the Kawa lecture notes by Valentino Tosatti are excellent (these notes are on the arXiv).